# Campos de formulario salen vacios en el mail que se envia

Tags: php, formularios

tengo un formulario en php que funciona al subirlo al servidor (envia correo), pero los campos que rellena el usuario salen en blanco (con lo cual no envia ninguna informacion en realidad)

este es el formulario

```
<form action="contact_process.php" method="post" id="contactForm">
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="border">
    <div class="ser-in-box"><input class="form-control datepicker-example8" placeholder="Fecha de Llegada" type="text"></div>
    <div class="ser-in-box"><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker-example8" placeholder="Fecha de Salida"></div>
    <div class="ser-in-box">   
    <div class="select-box">
                            <select class="select-menu" name="selectMenu">
                                <option value="default">Escoja su Espacio</option>  
                                <option value="1">1</option>    
                                <option value="2">2</option>    
                                <option value="3">3</option>    
                                <option value="4">4</option>    
                            </select>
                    </div>
    </div>
<div class="ser-in-box">
     <div class="select-box">
                            <select class="select-menu" name="selectMenu">
                                <option value="default">Personas</option>  
                                <option value="1">1</option>    
                                <option value="2">2</option>    
                                <option value="3">3</option>    
                                <option value="4">4</option>    
                            </select>
                    </div></div>
<div class="ser-in-box chk-button"><button type="submit" class="res-btn">Haga Su Reserva</button></div>
    </div>

</div>
</form>

y este el php que deberia hacerlo funcionar y por tanto enviar la informacion

<?php

    $to = "dingoymax@gmail.com";

    $name = $_REQUEST['Nombre'];
    $from = $_REQUEST['E-mail'];
    $arival_date = $_REQUEST['Fecha de llegada'];
    $departure_date = $_REQUEST['Fecha de salida'];
    $chooseAdults = $_REQUEST['Escoja su Espacio'];
    $chooseChildren = $_REQUEST['Personas'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['Su mensaje'];


    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    $subject = "Solicitud de Reserva";

    $body = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Industrial Mail</title></head><body>";
    $body .= "<table style='width: 100%;'>";
    $body .= "<tbody><tr><td style='border:none;' colspan='2'>Equipo de Reservas, <br /> <br />Teneis una nueva solicitud de reserva <br />Los detalles de la misma figuran a continuacion:</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;height:10px'>&nbsp;</td><td style='border:none;'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>Nombre</td><td style='border:none;'>{$name}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>E-mail</td><td style='border:none;'>{$from}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>Fecha de llegada:</td><td style='border:none;'>{$arival_date}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>Fecha de salida:</td><td style='border:none;'>{$departure_date}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>Escoja su Espacio:</td><td style='border:none;'>{$chooseAdults}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>Personas</td><td style='border:none;'>{$chooseChildren}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>Su mensaje</td><td style='border:none;'>{$message}</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;height:10px'>&nbsp;</td><td style='border:none;'>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>Gracias</td><td style='border:none;'></td></tr>";
    $body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>El equipo de Pazo Catoira</td><td style='border:none;'></td></tr>";


    $body .= "</tbody></table>";
    $body .= "</body></html>";

    $send = @mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

    if($send)
    {
        echo 'Gracias por contactar con Pazo Catoira. Recibirá su respuesta a la mayor brevedad posible';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Ocurrio un error durante el proceso de envío. Por favor intentelo de nuevo';
    }
?>
```

Seguro que sera una cosa sencilla pero ya no se como poder solucionarlo despues de intentar todo

Gracias

Comment: Te falta poner las etiquetas `name` correctamente como ya se ha dicho. Pero también, todo aquello que quieras recoger con `$_REQUEST` debe estar **dentro del formulario**, de lo contrario, no se enviarás cuando pulses en el botón para enviar. Yo veo que tú tienes elementos fuera de la etiqueta `<form>`.

Comment: eso me valio para la fecha de llegada y de salida , pero el resto de los campos continuan sin funcionar. ¿podrias indicarme que elementos estan fuera de la etiqueta <form> ?

Comment: Por ejemplo si esta linea es donde va el nombre que quieres: `$body .= "<tr><td style='border:none;'>Nombre</td><td style='border:none;'>{$name}</td></tr>";`, debe estar dentro de la etiqueta `form` y preferiblemente en un input: `<input name="Nombre"   type="text" placeholder="Escriba el Nombre" />`  ... y así, todas las que quieras recuperar con `REQUEST` cuando el formulario se envíe.

Comment: Solo una ultima pregunta , el formulario ya funciona enviando los datos correctamente pero algo debe estar mal en el php porque el correo que se recibe muestra toda la informacion excepto la de quien manda el e-mail haciendo la consulta (cosa bastante importante por otro lado para saber de donde llega la consulta) . Muchas gracias

Comment: Quizá no estés recuperando bien la dirección de quien envía. En tu código sería la variable: `$from = $_REQUEST['E-mail'];`  Por todo lo que ya se ha dicho, en tu formulario debe haber un `input` cuyo name sea `E-mail` donde se escriba la dirección del que envía, entonces la recogerá con el REQUEST y aparecerá en el mensaje enviado. Puede que haya un fallo en tu código en ese sentido.

Answer (score 1):

En el html te falta el atributo **name**:

```
<input name="fecha_llegada" class="form-control datepicker-example8" placeholder="Fecha de Llegada" type="text">
```

En php, $_REQUEST se refiere a este atributo:

```
$_REQUEST['fecha_llegada']
```

No utilices espacios, ni otros caracteres extraños.

Answer (score 1):

Saludos el detalle esta en las siguientes líneas:

```
    $arival_date = $_REQUEST['fecha_llegada'];
    $departure_date = $_REQUEST['fecha_salida'];
    $chooseAdults = $_REQUEST['escoja_espacio'];
    $chooseChildren = $_REQUEST['Personas'];
    $message = $_REQUEST['Su_mensaje'];
```

Esos espacios no van, es decir los espacios entre las palabras pues causa confusión y pudiera interpretarse como un name de input diferente al que tu declaraste en tu HTML.

A sí mismo esos name deberían ser los mismos que uses en tu HTML es decirlas variables que ocupas al final de todo tu código tienen; prueba como yo los declaré y asi mismo nombralos en tus etiquetas input